# SwipeRefreshLayout in AppBarLayout not wrapping content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appbarlayout, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to implement pull to refresh but I'm having an issue with `SwipeRefreshLayout` not wrapping the child view's height. In the view preview and in a live build it appears to have 0 height.

The layout as as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include layout="@layout/child_layout" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I have also tried making the `SwipeRefreshLayout` the parent of the `AppBarLayout` without any success as well as putting a singular `LinearLayout` inside of the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. The only thing that seems to prevent the height of the swipe layout from being 0 is to set it statically but I want it to be dynamic based upon the height of the child view.

Is there something I'm missing here? It seems like there may be a bug with `SwipeRefreshLayout` because replacing it with a `LinearLayout` that also wraps the content works as expected.

Comment: What happens if you change the `layout_height` of the SwipeRefreshLayout view to `match_parent`?  Just thinking outloud..

Comment: Could you post the code for `child_layout`.

Comment: why you are doing inside the toolbar ?  Why you not make it separate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your `SwipeRefreshLayout` is inside the `Toolbar` and `AppBarLayout`. You must wrap AppBarLayout with another layout and put `SwipeRefreshLayout` below the `AppBarLayout`. An example is at the below.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.vsahin.moneycim.View.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:expanded="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_background">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I forgot to include in my original post but there is a Recycler View with bottom sheet below the App Bar Layout. The issue is that I need the app bar layout for the parallax effect when the bottom sheet is opened but I only want to support pull to refresh on the app bar layout.

Comment: Why you are fixing the AppBarLayout's height, it will not work if you change it to wrap_content

Comment: I want to do that because in my original code I put a fragment there. In my fragment I am using auto scale textview that fit in bounds. @Safeer

Comment: I think the problem is collapsing toolbar is match parent and if you do apparlayout wrap content layout cant draw layout. appbar will try to wrap content but collapsingtoolbar is match parent and it will try to match its parents but appbar dont have a fix size. @Safeer

Comment: I got caught up working on other things and just came back to this, but you were right. This works as expected. The reason why it initially didn't work for me was because I forgot about some programatic behavior logic that just needed to be updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if your `SwipeRefreshLayout` height is wrapping the content of your `child_layout`, then your `child_layout`height should be set to `match_parent` OR both `SwipeRefreshLayout` and `child_layout` height should be set to `match_parent` as shown in the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <!--Child View-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

`SwipeRefreshLayout` is a transparent `View`, so best solution to set it `match_parent` it will not conflict with other Views and don't include `View` or `Layout` within it, keep it clean

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        <include layout="@layout/child_layout" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

`SwipeRefreshLayout` has to be in top to overlay other layers and be clickable